# Are there infinite many primes that cannot be the largest prime factor of a Carmichael-number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization, carmichael-numbers

Let $S$ be the set of prime numbers $p$ that cannot be the LARGEST prime factor of a Carmichael-number.

The first elements of $S$ are : $$[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 43, 47, 53, 59, 83]$$

> Does $S$ contain infinite many primes ?

I could only find out those primes by enumerating all $2^{25}$ odd squarefree numbers containing no prime factor larger than $101$ (the $26$ th prime) , but there should be a better method. Any ideas ?

Comment: It's not even all that easy to prove that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers....

Comment: Exactly @lulu. That has been out of the  Peter's perpective on his interesting question.

Comment: Upon checking the database for the first $10^{18}$ Carmichael numbers the next candidate seems to be $10883$.

Comment: @jorisperrenet So, even those relatively small Carmichael numbers cover all the primes between $83$ and $10883$ ? Surprising. So, $83$ could well be the largest prime in $S$. The list can well already be complete.

Comment: I indeed found counterexamples for all the primes between $83$ and $10883$ (thus for all primes $83<p<10883$ I found a Carmichael number of which the largest prime factor is $p$).

Comment: So, the next challenge is to find an example for $10883$. It would be great if you would list the greatest prime factors beyond $10883$ occuring upto $10^{18}$ , if that does not cause too much work :)

Comment: Of course , if you formulate this as an answer , I will upvote and accept it.

Comment: The least example for $10883$ is Carmichael number $1051816836991541401 \   [11, 73, 79, 181, 1451, 5801, 10883]$.

Comment: For the people interested, the unverified $p$ below $30\ 000$ are now `[17483, 18059, 20627, 21059, 21563, 22613, 22739, 23159, 25307, 25799, 26927, 27143, 27239, 28019, 28499, 28517, 28643, 28979, 29243, 29483]` thanks to @MartinHopf.

Comment: Very good , I will soon begin with searches for examples.

Comment: $22227832073753341324104067556986081$ is an example for $p=17483$

Comment: $4115380927579429523336633612161$ is an example for $p=18059$

Comment: $73547336899151154286484116321$ is an example for $p=20627$

Comment: One can make use of a larger [database](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/Pseudoprimes/) to find more examples.

Comment: `17977693593227765761` is an example for $p=29483$, `2628357249090228481` is an example for $p=29243$ and `3910595648567176801` for $p=28979$.

Comment: `3248839262809967905` is an example for $p=28517$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are getting kinda long, so here it is.
I checked the larger [database](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/Pseudoprimes/) thanks to @MartinHopf.

I checked the database by checking for each pseudoprime if it is a Carmichael number and then finding the greatest prime factor of the number, I eliminated $p$ as possible addition to $S$ if I found that $p$ was the greatest factor of such a number.

The remaining candidates below $50\ 000$ are `[25799, 40883, 42023, 42443, 42683, 42767, 44159]`.

---

**Update:**
`77579217225595049581` is an example for $p = 25\ 799$.

The remaining candidates below $50\ 000$ are now `[40883, 42023, 42443, 42683, 42767, 44159]`.

---

**Update:**
`192231276682846353121` and `30691624706028820801` are examples for $p=40\ 883$.
`361362050102075568481` for $p = 42\ 023$.
`187245600667639628401` for $p = 42\ 443$.
`1421298370313927469001` and `1475526798515376902401` for $p = 42\ 683$.
`3276241962960743496721` and `824592027949741719361` for $p = 42\ 767$.
And

```
18474317205530955301
25086959880820862401
32793227139330403201
35249365392461726881
626067460857971232001
20726926900955087905
941595098724511030801
1947595024403123504401
7625997271344313144921
1191134505408294459601
18598551907931088038401
3290982924650209776001
17875561355805607977121
11058363534498776939521
2426379943337261168401
```

are all examples for $p=44\ 159$.
There are no remaining candidates below $50\ 000$.

---

**Update:** I raised the search limit to all $p$ below $100\ 000$ by eliminating the $120$ possible candidates (derived from the dataset) for $p$ between $50\ 000$ and $100\ 000$.

The algorithm I used to eliminate the candidates rests on finding primes $q$ and $r$ smaller than $p$ such that $n=mpqr$ (where $m$ is varied to search multiple numbers) is a Carmichael number with maximum factor $p$. (I first only used $p$ and $q$ but found that using three factors is even faster). Since $n$ is Carmichael, we have $p-1|n-1$, $q-1|n-1$ and $r-1|n-1$. Thus $n \equiv 1 \equiv mpr \pmod {q-1}$, $mqr \equiv 1 \pmod{p-1}$ and $mpq \equiv 1 \pmod{r-1}$. Using this we can find (using the Chinese Remainder Theorem) necessary congruences for $m$ and speed up our search.

Comment: Well done, an impressive search!

Comment: I see from your latest update, that you're quite familiar with constructing Carmichael numbers. Maybe of interest are two active links, dealing with [factorization](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=28570) and [construction](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=28643) of large Carmichael numbers. You are welcome - new ideas are always appreciated.